# Python won't download the entire file

Tags: python-3.4

```
while Fileupdate <= Filecount:
    print(Fileupdate)
    url = 'http://www.whatever.com/photo/'+str(Fileupdate)+'.jpg'
    try:
        a = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    except urllib.error.HTTPError as err:
        if err.code == 404:
            Fileupdate = Fileupdate + 1
            continue

    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, str(Fileupdate)+'.jpg')
    Fileupdate = Fileupdate + 1
    continue
```

It will search through the website and identify the web address to download the file from but starts the download and then freezes everytime after downloading 262.1kb of the file.  It won't download the rest of the file and it won't continue searching through the rest of the series.  Wish I hadn't lost my old code anymore...like a dummy I just started saving over top the old code.  At least it worked with a few flaws that I could probably now correct.  This isn't working worth a crap.

Comment: Are you sure that you aren't being throttled by the webserver you're downloading from?

Comment: Sidenote: 262.1k is probably 262144 which is 2^18. Might be a server issue.

Comment: I haven't had any issues in the past, only now since I made the change to the program.  I can go to the main website, outside of the program and view the file just fine.

Comment: `git init .` next time.

Comment: Just tried copying a known link to email, a link it would only let me download 262.1kb of, and I could download it just fine from email.

Comment: @Jonathon Reinhart not sure what you mean.  Higher in the code I do have a specific directory the file is supposed to be stored in.  Since it wasn't part of the relevant code is why I didn't post it.  From some quick research I think that is what you are meaning by git init.

Comment: @confused I was implying that you should `init` a local Git repository for every little project you work on like this, and `commit` your code whenever you make significant progress. Then when you screw up like you said you did here, you can simply go back and `checkout` the version that was working. And if the script turns into a full-fledged thing at some point, you can `push` it to GitHub or your own Git server.

Comment: I'm with the other guys though... your code is so simple, it's probably not broken. The fact that the download just stalls is almost certainly indicative of a server issue (intentional or not).

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? `wget` works for me via bash but this code also won't download the entire file. Its not a webserver or ISP issue. I'm running on Windows 10 and Python 3.7